# Passing Exchange Property between routes within same Camelcontext

Tags: apache-camel

I have below requirement:

Route 1:  `from(timer:foo?repeatcount=1).recepientList("rest service")`

Route 2:  `from(sourcequeue).process(new myprocessor()).to(destinationqueue)`

Need to use the json response from `route 1` and pass it to `Route 2` processor.
My problem is whenever i set the json response in exchange property and try to use in Route 2 processor it is null.

Any suggestion on how to pass the exchange property between these routes would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you cannot use **Exchange properties** to pass information between routes is that they **are not part of the message**.

Take a look at [this picture of the Camel Exchange model](https://fizalihsan.github.io/technology/camel-exchange-structure.PNG).

When a message is received by Camel, it embeds it into an Exchange and the Exchange is passed through the route. But when you send a message (`.to(...)`), only the message is sent.

Therefore you have to use (as answered by Thomas) the message body or a message header.

Comment: Does this apply to direct routes too? E.g. a direct route will not be able to see properties set in the previous route?

Comment: Direct routes are an exception because it is a Camel internal transport. So, **Exchange properties are kept between direct routes**. I guess that the whole Exchange is passed between them while a message that is sent to another transport technology (http, jms etc) has to be transformed in a message for this transport.

Answer (score 1):

If you use http camel component, the http response should be in the body. You can load it from your processor.

```
String json = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

from(timer:foo?repeatcount=1).recepientList("http://rest_service")
.to(direct:sourcequeue)
```

You can also use headers to pass data throw your route.

```
from(timer:foo?repeatcount=1).recepientList("http://rest_service")
.setHeader(“myJsonResponse”, simple("${body}"))
.to(direct:sourcequeue)

String json = exchange.getIn().getHeader(“myJsonResponse”, String.class);
```